# How to apply LIKE query on GROUP_CONCAT in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am performing `LIKE` query on `GROUP_CONCAT` which gives me 0 results which is wrong beacause `area_seq` are present for those overlapped areas.

Below is my query

```
select ar.area_seq
from area ar
where ar.name LIKE (select GROUP_CONCAT(overlapped_areas)
                    from overlapping_areas oa, area ar
                    where oa.area_seq = ar.area_seq)
```

> ```
> GROUP_CONCAT query results : adair county, orange county, baldwin county etc....
> ```

However, `GROUP_CONCAT(overlapped_areas)` gives my comma (,) separated overlapped areas. But, same I passed to area table then it should ideally return there `area_seq` but it simply returns no results.

Comment: Please show data which explains your query.  Your question is not clear just from what you wrote above.

Comment: Please see results of internal query results overlapped areas (names)

Comment: Can you add a sample table structure for tables `area` and  `overlapped_areas` please?

Comment: try `LIKE ...CONCAT('%',GROUP_CONCAT(overlapped_areas) ,'%') ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `FIND_IN_SET` here:

```
SELECT area_seq
FROM area
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(name, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(overlapped_areas)
                         FROM overlapping_areas oa, area ar
                         WHERE oa.area_seq = ar.area_seq)) > 0;
```

`FIND_IN_SET` searches for a string inside a CSV string of several terms.  For example:

```
FIND_IN_SET('Orange County', 'adair county,orange county,baldwin county')
```

would return `2`, because `orange county` occurs in the second position of the CSV list of places.  `FIND_IN_SET` returns 0 when no match occurs.

I feel that the following query should give the same result, minus the performance penalty of an unnecessary `GROUP_CONCAT` followed by a call to `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT area_seq
FROM area
WHERE name IN
(
    SELECT overlapped_areas
    FROM overlapping_areas oa
    INNER JOIN area ar
        ON oa.area_seq = ar.area_seq
);
```

Comment: @VVB There is probably a better way of writing the query though...I'm trying to find it now.

Comment: Okay, If gets please update the same. Maybe helpful performance wise

Comment: Also, if you could provide little explanation about FIND_IN_SET then it will help me as a novice mysql

Comment: Updated query gives 0 results

Comment: @VVB Without seeing your table structure and data, it is hard to guess at what the correct query should be.  Edit your question and show us data and structure.

Comment: Okay will update it currently making things up for PoC, so need sometime